# Fastest way to check thousands of gzip files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I created this snippet to loop through a folder and check if there is an invalid gz file and fix it by gzipping it again.
This works fine but only if there are only a couple of files. If there are thousands of files, this takes so long.

Is there a more optimized way to do this.

```
fix_corrupt_files()
{
  dir=$1
  
  for f in $dir/*.gz
  do
  
  if gzip -t $f;
    then :
  else
    log "$(basename $f) is corrupt"
    base="$(basename $f .gz)"
    log "fixing file"
    mv $f $dir/$base
    gzip $dir/$base
    log "file fixed"
  fi
  
  done
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the commands `mv $f $dir/$base` and `gzip $dir/$base` ? It seems you strip the `.gz` extension off of the gzipped file and re-gzip it. That makes no sense and won't fix a corrupted gzipped file.

Comment: "corrupt" may be a bit misleading sorry for that. the file is actually still intact I can "cat" it and can still see it's contents. it's just that even though it is in .gz format it is throwing "not in gzip format" error. that's why I'm doing the re-gzip to fix it.

Comment: I think I get it now. The file wasn't gzipped in the first place but somehow had got the `.gz` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a little speed up:

```
fix_corrupt_files()
{
  dir="$1"
  
  for f in "$dir"/*.gz
  do 
  {
    if gzip -t "$f";
      then :
    else
      log "$(basename "$f") is corrupt"
      base="$(basename "$f" .gz)"
      log "fixing file"
      mv "$f" "$dir/$base"
      gzip "$dir/$base"
      log "file fixed"
    fi
  } &
  done
  wait # wait for all background processes to terminate
}
```

Note that I'm assuming the `gzip` commands are your slow parts.

All I really did here was run your `if` statement in the background (with `{...}&`). So basically each `if` statement in your function is going to run in parallel.  There is a `wait` at the end of the function so it won't leave the function until all sub-processes complete. That may or may not fit your use case. Also be aware that `log` is going to get called essentially randomly and possibly out of order. Again, it really depends on your use case whether that matters.

Also note that I added double quotes where ever they *should* be.  Looks like you're are confident that there are not spaces in your file names, but it was giving me anxiety.

edit:
Also also note that this may bring your machine to its knees. I'm not familiar enough with `gzip` to know how resource intensive it is.  I also don't know how big your archives are. If that becomes a problem, you could add a loop counter that calls `wait` every X number of iterations.

Comment: {...}& + wait is a neat trick. I haven't used this but also I agree that incorrect use it could bring my machine to it's knees. l'm accepting this as an answer as this helped cut down processing time from 50mins to 15min.

Comment: @user2058738 I'm glad that helped.  I just wanted to point out that I just edited the code in the answer.  I removed the background (`&`) on the actual `gzip` call.  That line used to be `gzip "$dir/$base" &  # run in background`.  That was my original solution, and I forgot to take it out.  It wouldn't cause any issues that I can think of apart from unnecessary overhead (`if` process will end immediately assuming `log` has negligible runtime).

Comment: no worries. I noticed that too and removed it from my code.